# OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec: "\\":

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, api-platform.com

Hello i am new to docker and i am following the documentation in the website of API Platform to install mongodb with docker-compose in but i have a problem.

I have installed the api-platform destribution. This uses PosgresSQl as database but i want use Mongodb. The default version works just fine but mongodb it won't work.

Once i installed the mognodb extension in the Dockerfile the next step was to run `docker-compose exec php \ composer require doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle` and once i did this

i get error: `OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec: "\\": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown`

In the docker-compose.yml i have defined the following mongo container:

```
mongo:
    image: mongo
    environment:
          - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=api
          - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=api-platform
          # You should definitely change the password in production
          - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=!ChangeMe!
    volumes:
          - db-data:/var/lib/mongodb/data:rw
          # You may use a bind-mounted host directory instead, so that it is harder to accidentally remove the volume and lose all your data!
          # - ./docker/db/data:/var/lib/mongodb/data:rw
    ports:
          - "27017"
```

Comment: I think this is due to the backslash \ of the `docker-compose` command. It is here just to display the command on several lines instead of only one. Remove it and type the command on a single row, or keep it but make sure there is a line feed `\n` just after.

Comment: This worked. I succesfully installed the package running `docker-compose exec php composer require doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle` after running `docker-compose up -d`. Thank you sir.